# Stripe API, How to get "subscription.status" from definition of ListView from django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I'm trying to configure Django Stripe Subscriptions for Database WebApp.

I want to make sure only "paid user(subscribed user)" can search database. Therefore I need to check whether subscription.status is "active"

Here is ListView of **view.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from.models import TestEu
from django.views.generic import ListView
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from subscriptions.models import StripeCustomer 

#search 
class DbList(ListView):
    model = TestEu
    
    def get_queryset(self):

        stripe_customer = StripeCustomer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(stripe_customer.stripeSubscriptionId)

        if subscription.status == "active":
            sql = 'select * from test_eu'
            msg = "abcdefg"
            sql += " where eng_discription ~ '.*" + msg +".*' ORDER BY image_amount DESC " 
            object_list = TestEu.objects.raw(sql)
            return object_list
```

When executing the above code, an error message occurs at the code below.

**stripe_customer = StripeCustomer.objects.get(user=request.user)**

> NameError: name 'request' is not defined

In this paticuler situation, how can I define "request" to fetch Subscription data?

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `queryset()` method you have to use `self.request` to access the attributes of `request` object.

Basically, replace this -

```
stripe_customer = StripeCustomer.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

to

```
stripe_customer = StripeCustomer.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: The problem was solved. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

What is creating the call to `get_queryset`? The error seems accurate in that `request` isn't defined anywhere, so what do you expect this to be?

I'm not a Django expert so not sure how to configure this, but there seem to be extensive docs on user auth approaches, depending on your use case: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/

From the Stripe integration perspective, I would strongly recommend you store this subscription state in your own user model, and *not* depend on a call out to Stripe in order to check for access to your system. You should set initial state for your users when they sign up and then keep track of any state changes from Subscription webhooks ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#tracking)). If you get an event(s) that you interpret as a subscription no longer being active (according to your business rules), then you'd de-activate access on your user model.